# math.random in javascript, try to draw the last number

Tags: javascript, function, math, random, draw

I created a function in javascript to draw numbers but it does not draw the last number, the user informs 1 to 20 it only draws from 1 to 19.

```
function rand (min=0, max){
    const valor = Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    return Math.floor(valor)
}

function gerar(){
const min = Number(document.getElementById("minimo").value)
const max = Number(document.getElementById("maximo").value)
```

i try min=0 or min=1 and don't work.

Comment: can i know the max value ? can you ```console.log(max)``` it ?

Comment: `const valor = Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min` because the  number of values you want is 20 ... i.e. `20 - 1 + 1`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be need of small change, with the equation you are using you will need to pass [max + 1] for maximum number to be inclusive, or change the function with equation

```
(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1) ) << 0
```

Left shift operation by 0 effectively truncates the floating-point number's decimal part, leaving you with an integer. This works because bitwise operations in JavaScript automatically convert their operands to 32-bit integers, and shifting by 0 doesn't change the value but results in a conversion to an integer.

More details in comments, Thanks @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

Either will work for you.

Comment: Never use a bit shift without explaining why you're showing a bit shift.

Comment: Left shift operation by 0 effectively truncates the floating-point number's decimal part, leaving you with an integer.

Comment: [in your answer](/help/how-to-answer), not in a comment. You're not telling "me", you're telling everyone reading this answer =) (also note that it doesn't leave just "an integer", it leaves you with a 32-bit integer, which is a really important detail, because the standard JS number can model integers up to 53 bits, which is why you typically want Math.round _unless_ your math is your bottleneck)